# Passing $this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I rewrite this to use a common function, pretending that the common function would eventually have more than the 1 line of code in it:

```
$('.insert').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
$('.delete').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is just a variable, and like any variable you can pass it as a parameter to another function:

```
function my_func(obj) {
   $(obj).css('cursor','pointer');
}

$('.insert').hover(function() {
    my_func(this);
});
$('.delete').hover(function() {
    my_func(this);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Or if you just want to avoid duplicating code

```
$('.insert,.delete').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

Comment: See?  THIS is the reason I ask questons on Stackoverflow!  I always get alternatives that are better than I imaginged.

Answer (score 5):

Just pull your current code into a separate function:

```
var f = function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
};
```

and:

```
$('.insert').hover(f);
$('.delete').hover(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly...

```
function(elem) {
   $(elem).hover(function() {
      $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
   });
}
```